# Can't add domain to resolv.conf on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, squid

Im trying to setup Squid 4.8 on new server. As i understand

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

should contain nameserver, search and domain rows. I've added nameservers and search to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml and changed symlink /etc/resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. Tried to add domain in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, but nothing changed.

Ping from squid server to other servers in my domain works fine.

What am i doing wrong? Is it necessary to add domain row to resolv.conf in my case?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 or the 2018-October release of Ubuntu has 9 months of supported life, which reaches EOL today.  I'd start by installing Ubuntu 19.04 and setting yourself up there, rather than waste time on something that reaches EOL in a few hours, otherwise use a LTS release (such as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which has 5 years of supported life).

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) End of Life reached on July 18 2019](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2019-July/000247.html)

Answer (score 0):

So, i've installed and configured squid and everything works fine. You dont need to add domain to resolv.conf in this version.